# How to select rows in data frame not in the list of indexes?

Tags: r

I want to select the rows in a data frame whose indexes are not in a list of rows, eg:

```
split = 0.70
train_subset <- df[sample(nrow(df), 
                          size=split * nrow(df)),]
test_subset = ?
```

How can I create test_subset from df and train_subset?

Comment: Please remember to make your examples reproducible (i.e. include the data)

Comment: I think my question is generic enough that including the data isn't necessary. The same code could apply to any data frame.

Comment: Then use a reproducible dataset. The requirement to include a reproducible example for this type of question is just that, a requirement, not a suggestion.

Comment: Please point me to documentation of requirements for questions posted on StackOverflow. Specifically, where does it require a "reproducible dataset"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
split <- 0.70
train_rows   <- sample(nrow(df), size = split * nrow(df))

train_subset <- df[train_rows,]

test_subset  <- df[-train_rows,]
```

Store the rows you want to sample in a vector. Then use that to select training and testing sets.

Comment: I like this, as it is most concise. I had forgotten about the - operator for subsetting.

Answer (score 1):

We need to use `replace= FALSE` if we don't need the same rows repeating.

```
i1 <- sample(nrow(df), size=split * nrow(df), replace = FALSE)
```

then, create a second index based those values in the sequence of rows that are not in 'i1'.

```
i2 <- setdiff(seq_len(nrow(df), i1)
```

and `subset` the dataset to create the 'test' and 'train' datasets.

```
train_subset <- df[i1,]
test_subset <- df[i2,]
```

Comment: Thanks, it is useful to know about the setdiff function.